# C3 charts data label custom alignment

Tags: jquery, html, css, c3.js

In my application I have implemented a grouped bar chart with line using c3 charts. For achieving the line over grouped bars, I am using the same value of a bar for drawing the overlay line and hiding that line's data table using css.

[image]

But the remaining 2 data labels are not aligned in the center. how to fix this issue?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/px439vmv/114/)

JS Code:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        x : 'Year',
        columns: [
            ['Year', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016'],
            ['test1', 20, 20, 25, 35, 45, 50, 50,55, 58, 58],
            ['test2', 80, 81,76, 66, 56, 51, 50, 46, 44, 44],
            ['Line Data', 20, 20, 25, 35, 45, 50, 50,55, 58, 58]
        ],
        groups: [
            ['test1', 'test2']
        ],
        type: 'bar',
        types: {
            'Line Data': 'line'
        },
        colors: { 
          'test1': '#c0c0c0',
          'test2': '#d4b012',
          'Line Data': '#000'
        }
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'category'
        },
        y : {
            tick: {
                format: function (d) { return d+"%"; }
            }
        }

    },
    grid: {
        y: {
            show: true
        }
    }
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

CSS Code:

```
g .c3-legend-item.c3-legend-item-Line-Data,.c3-tooltip-container .c3-tooltip-name--Line-Data {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than hiding that legend item with css, use the c3 configuration syntax for legend:

```
...
grid: {
    y: {
        show: true
    }
}
legend: { // add this bit
    hide: ['Line Data'],
}
```

http://c3js.org/reference.html#legend-show (legend-hide is the one below but its anchor link is broke)